# Calculating the number of all possible connected regions on a discrete grid

Tags: combinatorics

Given an $N \times M$ grid. How would one calculate the number of possible connected regions of that grid? A connected region is a set of cells in this grid such that there is a path from any cell from this set to any other cell from this set where the path cannot contain cells outside of this region.

Comment: It might help to include a definition of *connected region*.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you by an  example draw ?

Comment: Presumably you mean a subset of the squares defined by the grid such that all the squares are connected. I don't see a simple way to compute it except by searching the tree of adding squares.  You can use symmetry and sliding around small regions to reduce the task.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean Ross.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I think DFS by adding connected squares would be less efficient than my method even for large $m,n$ (my method would always make $m$ the smallest of the two)? I also think sliding around small regions would yield asymptotically zero improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m$ is small, it is easy using recurrence relations (dynamic programming). Let $f(n,p)$ be the number of configurations in an $m \times n$ grid such that each chosen cell is connected by chosen cells to the $n$-th column and the $n$-th column has connectivity pattern $p$, where connectivity pattern describes not only which cells of the column are in the region but also how they are connected. Clearly $f(n+1,\cdot)$ can be computed from $f(n,\cdot)$, and there are at most $(m+1)^m$ connectivity patterns. Thus the algorithm will have time complexity at most $O((m+1)^{2m}n)$ assuming $O(1)$ arithmetic. (But I did not check whether the state transition is actually more efficient than the worst case.)